# Regular expressions to capture separated lines

Tags: regex

I'm trying to grab some text with regular expressions.
I can easily get a single line of text, but can't figure out how to get 2 lines of data separated with non important text.
Consider the following sample.
There is a raw text like this:

```
Needed
don't caputure
text here
number of lines for 
noise can differ
Moreneeded
more not needed
```

I need to get line 1 and line 6, that is: "Needed" and "Moreneeded".
If those lines come one after another, then it's peace of cake.
But how can I get them if they are separated with several lines of noise and the amount of noise is always different?

Thank you.

Regards,
uch

Comment: In which language/tool you are doing this?

Comment: How do you know which lines are needed?

Comment: I use C#. I have patterns for both of the lines. But for simplicity lets assume just these two words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex between the quotes
"< head >(.|\n)*?< tail >"
here < head > => needed 
< tail > => more needed.

Comment: Dear Deepak, Thanks, it works like a charm. 8 letters do all the magic)))). So easy... I just can't understand why I didn't come to that myself. Thanks once again.